# Can't pass on variables to a function

Tags: java, android

EDIT: I did what Tritan Man said and it obviously worked. Thanks.

I am very new to developing and am making a simple "Whack-a-Mole" app. I need a few variables throughout the whole program, such as one to report if the mole is up or down. If I define the variables right after this:

```
public class WhackAMole extends Activity {
```

...my app crashes and gives me a message saying the app has stopped.

If I put the variables in the `onCreate` function, then pass them on to each function, a handler of mine gets underlined in red and says `The Constructor Object (my variables) is undefined.` - even though I have defined it everywhere. This is how it looks:

```
    mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable(Mole1_Btn, Mole2_Btn, Mole3_Btn, mole1_on, mole2_on, mole3_on) 
    {
        public void run(ImageView Mole1_Btn, ImageView Mole2_Btn, ImageView Mole3_Btn, boolean mole1_on, boolean mole2_on, boolean mole3_on) 
        {
            changeMole1(Mole1_Btn, Mole2_Btn, Mole3_Btn, mole1_on, mole2_on, mole3_on);
        }
    }, wait);
}
```

This all becomes underlined. Why does this crash in the first example, or why does the handler gives me an error for the second one?

Here is the error log from when I put the variables where I said at the start:

```
08-08 12:05:27.622: D/libEGL(9830): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_adreno200.so
08-08 12:05:27.622: D/libEGL(9830): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_adreno200.so
08-08 12:05:27.632: D/libEGL(9830): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_adreno200.so
08-08 12:05:27.632: I/Adreno200-EGL(9830): <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:265>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build:  (CL3544079)
08-08 12:05:27.632: I/Adreno200-EGL(9830): Build Date: 03/28/13 Thu
08-08 12:05:27.632: I/Adreno200-EGL(9830): Local Branch: adreno_20130328
08-08 12:05:27.632: I/Adreno200-EGL(9830): Remote Branch: 
08-08 12:05:27.632: I/Adreno200-EGL(9830): Local Patches: 
08-08 12:05:27.632: I/Adreno200-EGL(9830): Reconstruct Branch: 
08-08 12:05:27.702: D/OpenGLRenderer(9830): Enabling debug mode 0
08-08 12:06:06.750: D/GestureDetector(9830): [Surface Touch Event] mSweepDown False, mLRSDCnt : -1 mTouchCnt : 7 mFalseSizeCnt:0
08-08 12:06:06.811: D/AndroidRuntime(9830): Shutting down VM
08-08 12:06:06.811: W/dalvikvm(9830): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41be1ac8)
08-08 12:06:06.821: E/AndroidRuntime(9830): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-08 12:06:06.821: E/AndroidRuntime(9830): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.myfirstapp/com.example.myfirstapp.WhackAMole}: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-08 12:06:06.821: E/AndroidRuntime(9830):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2172)
08-08 12:06:06.821: E/AndroidRuntime(9830):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2296)
08-08 12:06:06.821: E/AndroidRuntime(9830):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:151)
08-08 12:06:06.821: E/AndroidRuntime(9830):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1281)
08-08 12:06:06.821: E/AndroidRuntime(9830):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-08 12:06:06.821: E/AndroidRuntime(9830):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-08 12:06:06.821: E/AndroidRuntime(9830):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5293)
08-08 12:06:06.821: E/AndroidRuntime(9830):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-08 12:06:06.821: E/AndroidRuntime(9830):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-08 12:06:06.821: E/AndroidRuntime(9830):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
08-08 12:06:06.821: E/AndroidRuntime(9830):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
08-08 12:06:06.821: E/AndroidRuntime(9830):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-08 12:06:06.821: E/AndroidRuntime(9830): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-08 12:06:06.821: E/AndroidRuntime(9830):     at android.app.Activity.findViewById(Activity.java:1886)
08-08 12:06:06.821: E/AndroidRuntime(9830):     at com.example.myfirstapp.WhackAMole.<init>(WhackAMole.java:17)
08-08 12:06:06.821: E/AndroidRuntime(9830):     at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
08-08 12:06:06.821: E/AndroidRuntime(9830):     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
08-08 12:06:06.821: E/AndroidRuntime(9830):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1071)
08-08 12:06:06.821: E/AndroidRuntime(9830):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2163)
08-08 12:06:06.821: E/AndroidRuntime(9830):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: Are you running this through the debugger? Does this not give you a more detailed error?

Comment: the run method gets underlined because there is no such constructor for `Runnable`, what you are doing is not creating a constructor. as for the error you will need to post the stack trace of the error

Comment: It would be helpful to see the error log

Comment: Dude, ca you explain a little bit mode what exactly are you trying to do. I can't understand your idea from your question.

Comment: I posted it but I obviously posted it incorrectly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that's a wrong implemntation , the right Runnable implementation has this basic structure

```
new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    //the code to be run
  }
};
```

Edit : to use arguments inside run() you can declare them as final

Comment: Ok Thanks, but is there any way to make the Runnable run only after a certain amount of time like my first one was doing? Or at least what I thought it was doing.

Comment: And the arguments were already final, or at least they are in the onCreate function.

Comment: You could make a while or for-loop in the runnable. while(amountTimes) { .. };

Comment: if you mean adding a time delay before executing the code in run() , you can use the Thread.sleep(millis) to do it

Answer (score 0):

That's not how runnable works. You need to use no constructor and no args to run() then you need to use the final keyword on any variables you are passing to an anonymous class like that.